# Display dynamic data from database in a Modal Popup

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I have a list of data already stored in my database, I am able to query the database to list out a few presentable data in a table row. Each row has a dynamic link to a modal popup that displays more data about that particular row. However, when I click on each link for each row, only data from the last row pop-ups. other rows don't pop up.

My code is below.

Table

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                  <tbody>
                    
                  <tr>
                    <?php 
                        $curid = 0;
                         while($rstransaction = mysqli_fetch_array($gettransactions)){ 
                    ?>
                    <td scope="row" style="width:60%;"><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                  data-bs-target="#viewtransaction<?php echo $rstransaction['id']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Transaction ID: 0000<?php echo $rstransaction['id']; ?></a></td>
                    <td scope="col"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></td>
                    <td scope="col"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i></td>
                    <td scope="col"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Analytics</td>
                    <td scope="col"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> Add Stakeholder</td>
                   </tr>
                    
                    <?php $curid = $rstransaction['id'];  } ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Code to the modal popup just before the footer div

```
<?php 
    $displaytransaction = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE id = '$curid'");
    $showtr = mysqli_fetch_array($displaytransaction);
    $showtrid = $showtr['id'];

    ?>
     <!-- View Transaction -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="viewtransaction<?php echo $showtrid; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div style="--bs-modal-width: 90% !important;" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Transaction ID: 0000<?php echo $showtr['id']; ?></h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           <!--content-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <p>Transaction Date: <?php echo $showtr['created_at']; ?></p>
                    <p>Crop Type: <?php echo $showtr['croptype']; ?></p>
                    <p>Crop Specification: <?php echo $showtr['cropspecification']; ?></p>
                    <p>Use: <?php echo $showtr['cropuse']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <p>Buyer: <?php echo $showtr['buyer']; ?></p>
                    <p>Buyer Rep: <?php echo $showtr['buyer_rep']; ?></p>
                    <p>Buyer State: <?php echo $showtr['buyerdestinationstate']; ?></p>
                    <p>Buyer LGA: <?php echo $showtr['buyerdestinationlga']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div>
                    <p>Quantity <br>
                    <?php echo $showtr['quantity']; ?>
                    <p>Amount <br>
                    <?php echo $showtr['cropvalue'] * $showtr['quantity']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So for each result record of the query in your first snippet, you are making an individual query in your second snippet then? This should loop over _one_ query result _twice_.

Comment: So i'm picking the transaction id from the first snippet to use in generating the display for the second snippet. How do I make it loop twice over a query result?

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php to reset the pointer to the first record, and then just loop over the result again.

Answer (score 0):

You set `$curid` php varible in a loop, but you use the variable's value outside of the loop, therefore its value will be the last value set in the loop.

It is not clear from the code snippet how the modal window's code should get the id of the row you want to display. If your intention is to pre-generat the modal window for all rows, then you need to loop through all trnsactions and use the transaction id retrived from the query.

If you want to dynamically load the selected transaction's detsils, then you need to use ajax to fetch the value.